# Can you add a Class Method to the Core Module Class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is it possible to add a core method to the Module class in Ruby?  I want to do something like this (messed around with the idea yesterday, just whipped this together in a second):

```
module MyModule
  base do
    has_many :something
  end
end

# implementation, doesn't work though... reason for the question
Module.class_eval do
  def self.base(&block)
    class_eval do
      def self.included(base)
        base.class_eval(&block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I create a module, I can't access that method:

```
$ module User; end
$ User.base
NoMethodError: undefined method `base' for User:Module
```

Any ways to do this?

**Update**

This works!  Thanks @Jörg W Mittag.  Makes it much easier to read for Rails `has_many` and such:

```
class Module
  def base(&block)
    metaclass = class << self; self; end
    # add the method using define_method instead of def x.say so we can use a closure
    metaclass.send :define_method, :included do |base|
      base.class_eval(&block) unless block.nil?
      base.class_eval <<-EOF
        extend  #{name}::ClassMethods
        include #{name}::InstanceMethods
      EOF
    end
    block
  end
end
```

Like this example:

```
module UserRoleBehavior
  base do
    has_many :user_roles
    has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # ...
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    # ...
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UserRoleBehavior
end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add a method to the `Module` class, you simply add a method to the `Module` class:

```
class Module
  def base
    # ...
  end
end
```

In your code, you were using

```
def self.base
  # ...
end
```

This syntax (`def foo.bar`) is the syntax for adding a singleton method named `bar` to the object referenced by `foo`, which is actually really just adding a regular instance method to the singleton class of the object referenced by `foo`.

So, in your code you were adding a singleton method named `base` to the object referenced by `self`, which inside of `class_eval` is the class object itself, in this case `Module`. The reason why singleton methods are *called* singleton methods, is because they only exist on a single object. In your case, the method `base` exists only on the object `Module`, not on any other object, and in particular not on the object `User`. In other words: the *only* way to call the `base` method is as `Module.base`, because that is the only object that you added it to.

It took me quite a while to wade through your three(!) nested `class_eval`s to find out what it is that you are trying to achieve. Which wasn't made easier by the fact that your code doesn't even actually work, even *if* defined on the correct class, because `def` creates a new scope, and so `block` is undefined in the innermost `class_eval`.

Apparently, what you are trying to do is this:

```
class Module
  def base(&block)
    define_singleton_method(:included) do |base|
      base.class_eval(&block)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: RE: "In other words: the only way to call the base method is as Module.base, because that is the only object that you added it to." Well technically you can also call `base` on the `Class` class too, since singleton methods are inherited ;)

Comment: I'm getting that the block is undefined in the line `base.class_eval(&block)`... any thoughts?  I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, so there's no `define_singleton_method`, I implemented the above (updated question).

Comment: @viatropos: in which code, mine or yours? If it's your code, then yes, that's what you would expect: `def` creates a new scope, so there is no variable named `block` in scope, as I already explained in my answer. If it's my code, then you must have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @viatropos: I just cut&pasted your code and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag, you saved me a lot of looking around! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you add it by defining the method in the module module:

```
class Module
    def new_method
       ...
    end
end
```

Be very careful with this, as it effects all code that uses Module.